# Can not show changed value to hidden field with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, hidden-field

I have a checkbox and 2 number input fields:

```
<input name="exercise[hold]" type="hidden" value="0"><input class="te-cb" id="exercise_hold" name="exercise[hold]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input class="exerciseReps input-mini" id="exercise_number_of_reps_in_set" min="0" name="exercise[number_of_reps_in_set]" placeholder="Reps" type="number" style="display: none; ">
<div class="input-append te-len" style="display: inline-block; ">
    <input class="exerciseLength input-mini" id="exercise_length" min="0" name="exercise[length]" placeholder="Length" type="number">
    <span class="add-on">sec</span>
</div>
```

One input field is hidden with js:

```
$('.te-len').hide()
```

In form above there is also text input field with auto competition which gets the data with ajax (that is not relevant here). With jquery I am setting the values of input fields of form with data I got from server.

I also show hidden field if value for checkbox is true:

```
if data[selected].hold
    $('.exerciseReps').hide()
    $('.te-len').show()
```

and that works

Every field is set correctly accept the hidden field, that field is empty.

The weird thing is that I placed alert of that hidden field's value after it has been set and alert shows the value that should have been set but the value is not visible

```
$('.te-len').val( data[selected].length )
alert $('.te-len').val()
```

Note: the js code is actually coffescript.

Comment: if `alert $('.te-len').val()` is correct, what do you mean by "the value is not visible" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are setting value to a `div`.  Although use of `val` works, this function is primarily used on form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`.

If you mean to replace the content of the `div.te-len` then you could use either `html` or `text`:

```
$('.te-len').html( data[selected].length )
```

But it sounds like you are trying to show `data[selected].length` value in the `input.exerciseLength` numeric field.  For that you should be using:

```
$('#exercise_length').val( data[selected].length )
```

Comment: I accidentally put te-len class to div instead of input which is inside that div